# Forwarding Boost Log to File drops Meta-Informations

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am using the boost-log library like this:

```
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "My sample output";
```

and I hope, I do not need to change this.

The output looks like this

```
[2013-10-31 17:19:19.044701] [0x3f1e6740] [info]    My sample output
```

The problem:

I am trying to forward this from stdout to a file.

When I try something like this

```
boost::log::add_file_log("sample.log", boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true);
boost::log::add_common_attributes();
```

the output of exactly the same `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` look like

```
My sample output
```

What can I do to get my beloved meta information back?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time trying around, I figured it out myself.

I simply added

```
boost::log::register_simple_formatter_factory< boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char >("Severity");
boost::log::add_common_attributes();
boost::log::add_file_log("sample.log",
                         boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true,
                         boost::log::keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%ProcessID%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%]: %Message%" );
```

As one of the first lines. This writes the log to sample.log

The key seems to be that `add_file_log` overrides the style of BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL. Adding my own `boost::log::keyword::format` solved this issue.